# Word Styles out of sync

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, microsoft-word-2013

Our company upgraded to Microsoft Word 2013. When opening a document created in a prior version of Word, the Navigation Pane still shows the correct hierarchy for headings (Heading 1, Heading 2, etc.). However, when I click in text that I know has a particular style, that style does not show as selected under Home/Styles. Instead, Normal is always selected. How can I get the ability to manage styles/headings back?

The title bar shows as Docname.docx [Compatibility Mode], if that makes a difference.